# В чем проблема моего регулярного выражения?

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Нужно заменить E на YE, если дальше идет хотя бы 1 большая буква
Пробовал такой код:
    $str = "EV";

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[] = '/E([A-Z])/';


$replacements = array();
$replacements[] = 'YE';


$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
```

Но он заменяет полностью, то что я ему указал в $patterns[] и я получаю на выходе 
YE, вместо YEV (как хотелось бы). 
В чем проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется Вы забыли добавить подстановку. Похоже должно быть

```
$patterns = array();
$patterns[] = '/E([A-Z])/';


$replacements = array();
$replacements[] = 'YE$1';


$str = preg_replace($patterns, $replacements, $str);
```

Comment: Помогло, но не могли бы вы объяснить, что именно делает 'YE$1'?

Comment: YE это то,что вам нужно добавить, $1 - подстановка паттерна в скобках
Когда '/E([A-Z])/' найдет совпадение (например 'EV'), то 'YE$1' составит замену YE+буква, идущая после 'E' (в нашем случае 'V'), что вместе составит 'YEV'

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать опережающую позитивную проверку *(или ссылку на подмаску, как в предыдущем ответе)*. Массивы тут тоже можно упразднить:

```
$str = 'EV';

$str = preg_replace('/E(?=[A-Z]+)/', 'YE', $str);

echo $str; // YEV
```